# Live Tile as item of GridView in Windows 8 store application in XAML C#

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, live-tile

I want to create windows 8 store app GridView item as Live Tile item will update automatically can we do that same as Start menu tiles of Windows 8 in XAML C#?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_ so far? Show your effort here.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: No i didnt try anything but as i know in GridView didnt allow or microsoft is not providing any Tile in GridView so my question is is there any control or anything on that i will work ?